# how to make a graph with the mean as zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a graph that arranges my values in such way that the mean is considered as zero in the "y" axis, and every other value either goes up or down in the "y" axis. Is there any way to do this in excel?

[image]

Comment: do you need labels on vertical (y) axis?

Comment: Do you have any sample data and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Horizontal axis crosses` value of vertical axis, set `axis value` to the desired one.
Unfortunately you can't enter a dynamic value, need to update it each time when your data changes.

[image]